# Typescript, how to turn a discrimated union into an object?

Tags: typescript

If the discrimated union is defined as follows:

```
enum KEYS {
  A= 'a',
  B= 'b'
  ...
}

type TUnion =
  | { keyType: KEYS.A; items: AType[]
  | { keyType: KEYS.B; items: BType[]
  ...
```

How can I define the type for an object where the key is a `keyType` and the value is the matching ìtems`, without doing it all manually?

The manual approach seems to work but repeats the key-to-possible values relation:

```
type TObj = {
  [KEYS.A]?: AType[]
  [KEYS.B]?: BType[]
  ...
}
```

Comment: Perhaps using distributive conditionals, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wj1BlW)?

Comment: What information do you have to pivot from `KEYS.A` to `AType`?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev It's defined in `TUnion`.

Comment: @caTS this looks awesome! Only that all object keys seem mandatory, not optional - I wouldn't know where to change that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a great utility type to take a discriminated union and two of its properties and transform it into a map of the keys to values:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (k: infer I) => void ? { [K in keyof I]: I[K] } : never;

type FromDiscriminatedUnion<U, K extends keyof U, V extends keyof U> = UnionToIntersection<U extends U ? {
    [_ in U[K] & PropertyKey]: U[V];
} : never>;
```

We distribute over the union and get the selected key and map it to a value. Since this produces another union, we need to turn this union into an intersection.

Lastly, if you want all the properties to be optional, wrap the output with `Partial`:

```
type Result = Partial<FromDiscriminatedUnion<TUnion, "keyType", "items">>;
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/weQEdw)

Answer (score 2):

Similar idea to caTS's, but a bit simpler: [tsplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA0gogTQMpQN4CgpagQSgXigCIBDIgGk2wCEDiAjC9AX3XQBcBPAB2FwBUefQuAj1gAJwDcHIVGqDedAM7sJASxABzGbKX8AqiHUB7EHVRQA1sE6LgALliIkAOhxSo69sAjKnOPYA2gC6UMxQAD5o1rb2TvDIrtSe3r7+8sFhzLpcSkamIPwmAJIgPhLKwADG7IUAPAYAfHRUABQGUMAAHj4gACbKUCQgnFAA-FBtVk4GAJT4TQBuJur9UE4gwEuSc129oINT006aAGaSUCULy6v9e5MlG1BbOxJseXzFMLYAaiQAGzAwEa+z6R0MxjMLUInR64KGkMKEywliCNjGmigBiCAHIMfZcSEQrM8Wk-ESIpttpJcnIICRuLx1rCoUVSuVJFVag1vn9AcD6kjoU02Ho+CZuHUzICALKM5l0AAKJAkdUBjTZxTKFW50pAQpMP04-yBIOFICaVvQQA)

```
enum KEYS {
    A = "a",
    B = "b",
}

type AType = number;
type BType = string;

type TUnion = { keyType: KEYS.A; items: AType[] } | { keyType: KEYS.B; items: BType[] };

type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type ToKeyValue<U extends TUnion> = U extends TUnion ?  { [key in U['keyType']]: U['items']} : never;

type mapped = UnionToIntersection<ToKeyValue<TUnion>>


type optionalMapped = Partial<UnionToIntersection<ToKeyValue<TUnion>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

It makes more sense to define your types the other way around: declare `TObj` first, and then you can derive your discriminated union from it.

```
type TObj = {
  [KEYS.A]?: AType[]
  [KEYS.B]?: BType[]
}

type TUnion = {
  [K in KEYS]: {keyType: K, items: Exclude<TObj[K], undefined>}
}[KEYS]

// type TUnion = {
//     keyType: KEYS.A;
//     items: AType[];
// } | {
//     keyType: KEYS.B;
//     items: BType[];
// }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggKuaBeKBvAhgLigZ2AJwEsA7AcwF8AoUSKAIQVpVQCNs8iyrKJiBXALZQA0gFEAmgGU0lKLBQBydAoA0s+opYLK3GtDgB5FgCsozdQG0xUgHQwAugH5s8RBfuXrkm3SfYGbh66iFBwAKrEhAD2xGYyclZQJCISkvbYqADWECCMENjCKknAEAI42KIAHgDGADZ8ACYQADyGJlb2RXzETQBmJBANAHxU5FapHpQA9FNQeqER0bHmM3Jr2bmIBal2ANzTs2vFpeWwee77q+RQAD4yq0cbedu2dJeHa4QlZf7n9u9QKhAA)

Comment: Marking the answer that solves the question but this is very helpful! (Why to exclude undefined?)

Comment: `undefined` is excluded because your `TObj` type has optional properties, but you don't want these to be `undefined` in your `TUnion` type.

Comment: ah makes sense, thanks! Have to be careful not to have more keys defined than are in the `TObj` here. Maybe it would be cleaner to derive the enum from the `TObj`?